# how to use php sessions in embeded files?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a site https://one.com/go.php that (for example) contains :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id_ad'] = 123456;
header('Location: https://two.com/index.php');
```

and on https://two.com/index.php  user click and go to https://three.com/index.php that contains :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://one.com/2.php"></script>
```

and finally 2.php is:

```
 <?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
?>
alert("<?=$_SESSION['id_ad']?>");
```

can i access `$_SESSION['id_ad']` in 2.php ?
I tested only on firefox works.

////////EDIT//////

thank you to @Dimash to mention my mistake, but the main question still exists

Comment: No, the session cookie won't cross that kind of domain difference.

Comment: why on firefox works? @Scuzzy

Comment: actually you can not access to the session of another server, in specific server, because the session is stored in ram of server, and the session id always is stores in client cookies in private sections, so you can not access non of them

Comment: Why you do alert of uid if you created id_ad ?

Comment: Thank u , I fixed it in question. @Dimash

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I only want to access my sessions on three.com @charlietfl

Comment: That doesn't explain much.

Comment: where do u want exactly to be explained?@charlietfl

Comment: Guys you are wrong. It works.

Session !=  Cookie
Session is stored on server side for user's browse session and all javascript queries in such cases done on behalf of user and domain does not play any role. Server does not know which domain does request as all request does browser, so $_SERVER works fine.  Any javascript request does not different from tab reload and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, you just return javascript wrongly. Firefox for some reason works, but other browsers fails.

Here is working code:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
?>
alert("<?=$_SESSION['id_ad']?>");
```

Please note, that code was tested.

expect javascript file, not php with  tag, you need return reall js file, so you need add header content type, telling that it is js file + remove script tag, as it is not html but regular js file.

Comment: thank u , in my original code every thing has been considered. the exact problem is on other Browser

Comment: ? I did not understand, did it help you or you did not get an issue?  Recheck how you return file, all browsers works for me in my test, I see this only as one issue.

Comment: Issue can be if browser clean everything for session and in this case it will not work, settings of browser can play role.

Comment: thnak u, but for my and all of my users only works on firefox, @Dimish

Comment: Only debuging will help, at least show real link to test

Comment: it is not in English language, https://p30rank.ir/login.php  after login go to https://p30rank.ir/members/pages/gsearchshow.php

Comment: press green buttons it will go to another site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151773/discussion-between-dimash-and----).